# Get caret position using Active Accessibility (MSAA)

Tags: windows, winapi, caret, iaccessible

Can anyone give an example of using the MSAA in order to get the caret position (text insertion point and not the cursor).

[MSDN on MSAA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317990%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Thanks for any help,
Momico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caret tracking using MSAA can be achieved by using WinEventHook mechanism, and watching for the following events: EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE, EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY, EVENT_OBJECT_SHOW, EVENT_OBJECT_HIDE, EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE.

For further explanation and example visit the following links:

[Explains the use of WinEventHook](http://gpalem.web.officelive.com/EventTracking.html)

[SetWinEventHook (with example)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms696160)

Thx,
Momico.